# From generic measure theory to probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to transfer my knowledge of measure theory to probability theory. Because making it somewhat more "concrete" with examples in probability will hopefully make it easier to understand the generic (usages) of measure theory. I was thinking to use the normal distribution as an example.

I have $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$

Here I want to define a measurable mapping (function) $f(x):\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where f(x) is the standard normal distribution formula.

Because $\mathbb{P}$ is a measure, it assigns a real number to a given set $A\subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Hence $\int_A f(x) d\mu$=the probability of all $a \in A$ and $\mathbb{P(X)}=1$

What I don't understand is where the Lebesgue measure comes in here? And what guarantees that the integral is 1? Is this the nature of the f(x) due to the normal distribution function or is it something implicitly defined by the probability measure? Also I have read that the Lebesgue measure is part of this but I don't see where it fits in.

Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Things are not clear. Is $f$ supposed to be the PDF (probability distribution function) of standard normal distribution? Then it is by definition a nonnegative function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies $\int f\;d\mu=1$ where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.  And this with $\int_Bf\;d\mu=\mathbb P(N\in B)$ where $N$ is a random variable that has standard normal distribution and $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a Borelset. So $f$ is not a function $\mathcal A\to\mathbb R$. Also $\mathbb P$ assigns values to sets $A\in\mathcal A$ (not $A\subseteq\mathcal A$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and $X$ a random variable from $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ to $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, $X$ follows the standard normal distribution if $P_X$ (the pushforward measure of $X$ by $P$) is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, with density (Radon-Nikodym derivative) $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac12 x^2)$

Regarding the value of $\int f(x)dx$, note that $1=P_X(\mathbb R)=\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) d\lambda$? Meaning, $\underline{only}$ the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Dennis yes, but when integrating w.r.t the Lebesgue measure one does not need to write $d\lambda(x)$. Simply writing $dx$ is common usage.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info