# How is the Lebesgue measure related to a Normal distributed random variable $x\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, lebesgue-measure

After checking some olde posts about the Lebesgue measure and how dos it play its role when I random variable is normally distributed I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335064/from-generic-measure-theory-to-probability-theory). My question is, what happens when a random variable $X$ follows a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ instead of a standard normal?

Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a standard probability space and $x:(\Omega, \mathcal{F})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a random variable normaly distributed where $x\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. How is the lebesgue measure defined in here?

My attempt, correct me if I am mistaken. If $F$ is the CDF of the random variable $x$, namely

$$F(y)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}d\Lambda(x)$$

$F$ is strictly increasing and hence one-to-one and continuous. The range of $F$ is $(0,1)$ with $F(-\infty)=0$ and $F(+\infty)=1$. The inverse of $F$ is $x:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is also increasing, one-to-one and continuous with $x(0)=-\infty$ and $x(1)=+\infty$. Since $x_{|(0,1)}$ is continuous, it is measurable on the Lebesgue probability space. Observe that

$$\Lambda\left(\{\omega\in[0,1]:x(\omega)\leq y\}\right)=\Lambda\left(x^{-1}((-\infty,y])\right)=F(y)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean "how is the lebesgue measure defined in here"

Comment: @Andrew Think of the case similar to the previous post, in which we have $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ as the probability space and a measurable mapping (function) $f(x(\omega)):\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x(\omega))$ is some normal distribution with mean $\mu\neq 0$ and $\sigma^2$. Also, $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure, it assigns a real number to a given set $A\in \mathcal{F}$. I don't understand here where the Lebesgue measure comes and for what $\mathbb{P}$ stands for. Is $\mathbb{P}$ the Lebesgue measure? I attempt to define it for a r.v. $x\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Comment: @Andrew in the previous post, they define the Lebesgue measure as $\mu$ and say that $\mathbb{P}$ is the pushing formward measure or something like this....I have no idea that does this mean and they relate this somehow to the Random-Nikodym derivateve....ok even if this is the relation, they do not give any more thoughts to it....I only attempt to define the lebesgue measure $\Lambda(\dot)$ for a normal random variable and I do not think that I am far from being right to how this is defined....anyway...I hope I made it more clear to you....

Comment: I still don’t follow you…but what they are saying is that a Gaussian is a random variable which satisfies $P(X\in B)=\int_B f(x)dx$. It is then tautological that $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure and has radon nikodym derivative $f$. Here, $f(x)\propto \exp((x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma)^2)$

Comment: What I write above in mya attempt to define the Lebesgue measure for a normal random variable seems to be right or wrong? incomplete or complete?

Comment: Are you familiar with what Lebesgue measure is? Why are you trying to “define the Lebesgue measure for a normal random variable?”

Comment: Simple curiosity. But I do not follow you now...what do you mean If I am familair? Is something that itricky with Lebesgue measure? I thought it was a standard way to assign a measure to subsets of higher dimension Euclidean $k-$spaces, with $k$ referring to the dimension of the space....

Comment: If you feel that I am a little of....I am not familiar with measure theory as a topic, but I have some knowledge to some degree...If you are any maths postgraduate or some expert in the filed feel free to guide me....I don'w know what else to say